# SQL Server Backup to Network Share:Access is Denied

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, network-share

I am trying to setup a new job to backup two sql server databases to a network share twice a day.  I set the job up, and ran it manually for a test and it failed with access is denied (os error 5).  I forgot to request access to the share for the sql server service account.

I requested the access and it was granted, but now I am stilling getting access is denied when I try and run the backup or access the share via xp_cmdshell.

I have verified that the sql server service account has read/write access to the share by doing the following.I logged in to the sql server via rdp with the account, navigating to the share and creating/deleting files. I also checked in properties>securities>advanced>effective permissions.  The sql server account is shown as having read/write/modify permissions there as well.

I do have other jobs running in this instance that use different network shares with out any problems, so I am currently stumped.  Any suggestions?

Comment: You need to verify that the account has access to the UNC path.  Logging into the server and navigating to the local folder is not the same thing as accessing the share.  What you can do is open a cmd prompt, issue run-as  with the account credentials, and see if you can access the share directly.

Comment: I logged on to the server where the sql instance is running and navigated to the share via the unc path.  The share is on a remote server, not the sql box.